# apache2 is not listing the director

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

when we give ip in browser its not pointing to the index page. It showing error : "Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server" though index page is there in DocumentRoot.

If we give ip/index.php, it shows the page. Similarly when i opened test directory containg some files in browser (url : ip/test),it showing same error "Not found" instead of listing the files in the directory.

`Autoindex module was enabled . 
Tried giving Options +Indexes // enables the listing of files/folders in a directory
Permission for the directory also enabled.`

But still got the same error. When checked with log file , whenever i tried to open directory, showing "attempt to load directory"..But its not loading.

[This was happening with test server ,whereas stage server working properly. Also compared test and stage server configuration files like default [/etc/apache2/sites-enabled] , .htaccess , apache2.conf , httpd.conf, evrything seems to be same. ]

`.htaccess file`

```
      `Options +FollowSymLinks

       DirectoryIndex index.php`
```

`log file`
          `Attempt to serve directory: /var/www/`

**Document Root**  : /var/www/

Would someone have an idea to fix that one. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is index.php in /var/www ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need this line on top of your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will by default load `index.php` in each directory if request is for `domain.com/somedir` or just `domain.com/`

Comment: Tried and restarted the apache. Still showing the error. when we give folder name also its not listing the fikles inside that folder

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess is enabled? To verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: ok try placing `Options +FollowSymLinks` line on top of your .htaccess and retest

Comment: OK place your latest htaccess in question and also tell what is your document root Dir?